# How would I go about killing a process/application?

Tags: python, windows-7, process, kill

I'd like to be able to kill various programs mid-run using python. How would I go about this?

Something like this:

```
module.end_process('chrome.exe')
```

This little bit of code would shut down Google Chrome.

This is in Windows 7, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill

```
os.kill()
```

Although, you have to have the PID to use os.kill()- I'm not sure how to find a PID from a proc name with windows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Python Win32 Extensions](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) to handle Win32 processes from Python. You can use the approach explained in this mail [thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2005-February/002943.html) to find out handle of the executable (process) which you want to kill. You can then pass the obtained handle to method `win32Process.TerminateProcess` to kill the application.